# How can I change background of several cells with a click?

Tags: java, swing, background, jtable

I have a table which every cell keep a string. Actually I used the table as a page of book and it contains text. My problem is that I want to click on a cell and all similar words' background color in the table change to one unique color. For instance, when I click on the cell which contains 'and', all 'and' in my table become highlighted. I implemented defaulttablecellrenderer and I know that when java wants to draw table recall it for every cell. I tried to use intrinsic repetition capability and set the color but it does not work in the way I expected. These are my codes:

```
JTable t=new Jtabale();
//Filling my table....here....
t.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                    int column=((JTable)e.getSource()).getSelectedColumn();
                    int row=((JTable)e.getSource()).getSelectedRow();
                    JTable table=(JTable)e.getComponent();
                    Object myS=table.getValueAt(row, column);//value of that cell saved
                    CustomCellRenderer r=(CustomCellRenderer)table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                    r.setCell(myS);

                    table.repaint();
                }
            });
```

and this is my DefaultTableCellRenderer implementation:

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

Object myStr;

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
{

    Component c=super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);


    if(myStr==value){
        c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    else
        c.setBackground(table.getBackground());
    return c;
}

public void setCell(Object val){
    myStr=val;
}
```

I do not know what's wrong with this code? This is only highlight that cell which I click. But I expected it change the background of several cells together! Even I put println inside the if but even it goes once in the if brace! I got confused. What is your idea?!

Comment: Don't use `==` when you compare objects, it only compares the references, use `Object.equals(Object)`.  I can't tell from the code whether this is causing your problem - if the objects being compared are strings then they should have been interned and the references would be equal, but if they're not then you use of `==` is probably what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes your guess was correct. But I do not know why when I change it to Value.equals(myStr). I get this error and at the first execution table do not paint correctly. but after some click java repaint it but still I get that error again.

Comment: The error 'at first execution' is probably due to a lack of `null` checking.  If you're still getting the error you need to ensure that the same instance of `CustomCellRenderer` is being used by all cells.

Comment: at CustomCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(CustomCellRenderer.java:22)
 at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)...

Comment: Thank dear Nick. U were right. <3